# Error while installing CodeLite IDE in Ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, ide

While installing CodeLite IDE in Ubuntu following error occurs.

Any idea?

**ERROR:**

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 codelite : Depends: libjbig0 but it is not installable
            Depends: liblzma5 (>= 5.1.1alpha+20120614) but 5.1.1alpha+20110809-3 is to be installed
            Depends: libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.18.0) but it is not installable
            Depends: libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. You may need to check your version of Ubuntu, and that you've added the correct repositories. If this is the problem, then the fix is very simple!

**Firstly**, check your version of Ubuntu. From terminal you can do this with the command `lsb_release -a`. The important part, for our purpose, is the codename. I'm using Ubuntu 13, aka "saucy".

**Now** let's look at the multiverse repository that you added. From the terminal you can do this with `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`. Go down to the end of the file, and you should see something like:

```
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://repos.codelite.org/ubuntu/ saucy universe
```

Make sure that your version has your ubuntu codename (in my case 'saucy'). The example code on the website is for Ubuntu 14, and so I **wrongly** had a 'trusty' source here. Edit the line so that it is correct for your version of Ubuntu, and then save and close the file.

**Lastly**, you'll need to update your repos so that the change goes through. From the terminal, run `sudo apt-get update`. All being well, you should now be able to `sudo apt-get install codelite` without the errors.

My problem was caused by too much cutting-and-pasting code from the codelite website. I followed exactly the same page as you did, and their example code is for people with Ubuntu trusy (14).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to be more specific on how you tried to install codelite.
The official Debian repository manages an ancient version of codelite which we (the codelite team) do not support.

In order to get the most up-to-date version (that we support) please install it from [codelite's official website](http://codelite.org/) (select the Download at menu at the top)

Before installing, make sure you delete the folder `~/.codelite` (incase you are upgrading)
Also, the official Debian installer is split into 2 pakacges `codelite` and `codelite-plugins` make sure you purge them both before installing codelite from our repository

Comment: download page took me http://codelite.org/LiteEditor/Repositories#toc1 and then I added apt repos for codelite.same error again. Note I am using free tril

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of [Howto install the latest codelite in Ubuntu - EuroBytes](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/howto-install-the-latest-codelite-in-ubuntu). I have tested the latest codelite on Trusty.

If you still have issues with codelite, remove like so: `sudo apt-get purge codelite`

Note that the dependencies links are dead. But, i managed to install it anyways:

[image]

<sup>codelite 6.1 on Ubuntu Trusty Thar 14.04. 
Image from: [Howto install the latest codelite in Ubuntu - EuroBytes][1]</sup>

Install like so:

```
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://repos.codelite.org/ubuntu/ $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://repos.codelite.org/CodeLite.asc
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install codelite wxcrafter
```

**Source**:

- [Howto install the latest codelite in Ubuntu - EuroBytes](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/howto-install-the-latest-codelite-in-ubuntu)